# row_numbers within mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr, rank, row-number

I am a little confused about row_number function, from the console we can see
it's just equal to rank function.

```
function (x) rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep")
```

but why when I try the code below which return an error using rank() while return id index using row_number which work totally fine. Why? btw, why does row_number() has no arguments within mutate function and return an index as the same length of rows as the dataframe?

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(id=row_number())

mtcars %>%
  mutate(id=rank())
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :   Evaluation error: argument "x"
>   is missing, with no default.

Comment: It appears to be a bug. In fact, if you change `row_number()` to `dplyr::row_number()`, it will yield the error message despite the fact that we're calling on the same function. As of now, I see various threads on https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues touching on this.